# hide last hr within a loop using css

Tags: html, css

I have nested `<hr>` tag in my html, without using specified traversing, how can I hide the last hr using css but not js? I can skip the loop using js but I want to use pure css, not sure why `:nth-of-type(1)` hide all the `<hr>`

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="m-l-20 m-r-20">
      <div><strong class="m-b-10">Indonesia</strong></div>
      <div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>
        <div class="item">
          <label>
            <span>Lazada ID</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="m-l-20 m-r-20">
      <div><strong class="m-b-10">Malaysia</strong></div>
      <div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>
            <span>Lazada MY</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>
            <span>Lelong MY</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="m-l-20 m-r-20">
      <div><strong class="m-b-10">Others</strong></div>
      <div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>
            <span>Alibaba</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g59e21ps/1/

Comment: You can we just add an id to the hr tag and hide it? Or are you trying to use it for an unknown number of hr tags?

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is here...

```
.modal-body .row div:last-child hr {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`:nth[-last]-of-type` is the nth last *child* of a given tag type in its parent element – not the nth last match in the entire document. You can find `<hr>`s that are children of last children with the child combinator `>`:

```css
.modal-body :last-child > hr {
  display: none;
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g59e21ps/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet.

```css
.modal-body .row div:last-child hr {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="m-l-20 m-r-20">
      <div><strong class="m-b-10">Indonesia</strong></div>
      <div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>
            <div class="sa-checkbox theme__blue checked" style="position: relative;">
              <input type="checkbox" cursor="false" name="5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a85" value="on" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></ins></div><span>Bukalapar</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>
            <span>Lazada ID</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="m-l-20 m-r-20">
      <div><strong class="m-b-10">Malaysia</strong></div>
      <div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>
            <span>Lazada MY</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>
            <span>Lelong MY</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="m-l-20 m-r-20">
      <div><strong class="m-b-10">Others</strong></div>
      <div>
        <div class="item">
          <label>
            <span>Alibaba</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```